# Google Chrome repeatedly asks me to sign in on YouTube with a popup?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, popups

When I'm on YouTube and signed into my account, a bare-bones popup repeatedly appears asking me for sign in details. I assume the sign in details are for YouTube, but the popup doesn't have any information besides YouTube's url and a Username and Password field.

[The popup in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpNu2.png)

When I'm not signed in to my Google account, the popup doesn't appear at all. It's only when I'm signed in. As well, when I enter my details and press Enter, the popup simply reappears with no indication as to why.

Comment: Do you have any plugins in Chrome?

Comment: Reddit Enhancement Suite, uBlock Origin, EZ Subreddits, Old Reddit Redirect, DarkReader, and Disable HTML5 Autoplay. Oddly enough this doesn't happen on another computer of mine with the same OS and Chrome setup, just this one.

Comment: Try to manually log out and log back in.

Comment: This unfortunately does not prevent the popup from showing up.